# Add fragment below another overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm was trying to display fragment below another fragment, but i'm facing Issue with view, when i invoke the 2nd fragment that should come below first fragment it's overlap.

My First fragment container `RelativeLayout` with Id `mainLayout` and 2nd fragment with Id `carLayout`.

I assume the issue with `XML` code.

My XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/carLayout">

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

i need to set fragment 2 below fragment 1

but it'as overlapping.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? add both fragment in same view and replace one by anther

Comment: explain more ? what happened after change relative  to frame layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand you need to set two fragment in same view

```
// add your first fragment 
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frame_container1 , YOUR_FIRST_FRAGMENT).commit;

// add your second fragment 
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frame_container2 , YOUR_SECOND_FRAGMENT).commit;



<linearLayout    android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2">
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</linearLayout>
```

or simply

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="YOUR FRAGMENT CLASS"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    </fragment>
```

Comment: you welcome , fragment could be in LinearLayout as well

Answer (score 0):

carLayout is a RelativeLayout so new fragment will be over the last one, change it to a LinearLayout with orientation vertical.

Comment: That is the same problem, you should read documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html, the simpliest way to do what you want is to declare 2 containers for fragments and add them into it, or use a linearlayout with 2 fragments in

Answer (score 0):

You need another view below your `carLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/anotherLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/carLayout">
</RelativeLayout>
```

The 'add' method adds a fragment to a view, so you can modify your method to use a different container every time:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment, int containerId) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(containerId , someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

case R.id.home_menu:
     fragment = new mainFrog();
     replaceFragment(fragment,R.id.carLayout);

public void Haraj_cars(View view) {
      fragment = new carFrog();
      replaceFragment(fragment,R.id.anotherLayout);
}
```